# android - post to facebook group

Tags: android, facebook

i am new to facebook api , i follow this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/) to post to my wall and its work

but i need to post to group

i add user_groups and user_likes

```
if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
                facebook.authorize(this,
                        new String[] { "email", "publish_stream","user_likes" , "user_groups" },
```

any one can help me 
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this simple code + tutorial to do what you want

https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook

Answer (score 1):

All the information you need is in the Facebook docs, including example code: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/group/feed

Don´t rely on old tutorials, publish_stream is deprecated and you don´t need user_likes for groups.

I suggest reading the changelog too, from top to bottom: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: is there any new tutorial for that

Comment: as i said, all the information you need is in the facebook docs. no need to use a tutorial, the docs include everything.